# When do we need to prove the measurabiliy of a function to write its integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : [1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x) \leq 5 \ \forall x \in [1,2]$. Then can we write $\int _{1} ^{2} f(x) \,dx \leq 5$. Or do we need to first prove the measurability of $f$ to write that last inequality? Of course, I am talking about Legesge integration and I am asking this because I see people usually does not prove the measurabilty and directly  write that last inequality.

Does one assume the measurability of $f$ before writing down that last integral inequality? If yes, then why it is ok to do so?

Comment: If $f$ is not measurable, then $\int_1^2 f$ has no sense.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to "prove" that $f$ is measurable before you "write" the integral.  But if you write it, and try to integrate a function that isn't measurable, the relevant limits won't exist or converge.  The integral you wrote down is undefined, somewhat like $0/0$.

Comment: Limit ? Where do you use a limite ton compute for example $\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_A$ ?

Comment: Um, in a bunch of places in the standard machine of sequences of step functions...

Comment: So, take $A$ non measurable. Which limit in $\int_{\mathbb R}\boldsymbol 1_A$ won't converge ?

Comment: The sequences of inner and outer measures on $A$... seriously, this is baby rudin stuff.

Comment: @Walace: if you really don't know where the limits are in the definition of measure and Lebesgue integration, it might be time to look at the definitions very closely.  The lebesgue integral is a convergent series.

Comment: If the relevant limit is undefined, then why usually people does not prove the measurability ?

Comment: @abir: It's hard to say without a specific example, but I will say this: there are definitely circumstances where you need to prove that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable before you use that as another step in a proof (every time you use that fact), and not doing so is a mistake.  In physics, people just assume that functions and other math objects are "nice".  I think it just depends on the context of the field.

Comment: @nomen : Let $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ a measurable space. If $A\in \mathcal F$, then $$\int_X \boldsymbol 1_A\,\mathrm d \mu:=\mu(A)$$ by definition ! There is no limits here. Lebesgue integral works the same !

Comment: Surb: $\mu$ is the limit of approximations of the inner and outer measure...  Just because you can do a bit of sleight of hand doesn't mean you're not showing that a series of series converges.